# Can the number of foreground threads be determined in .NET?

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net

I've searched a good deal on the topic and have found little results.  It seems adding foreground into the criteria on any engine I've used causes tons of entry level documents on threading in .Net.

In my current project I have a foreground thread within a static class that lies dormant until it is told otherwise.  It contains a queue of items that must be processed and the items application cannot close without all items being processed.  Right now I have a method that tells the thread that it should stop accepting new items and close when it is finished processing everything, but not everyone on the team remembers to call the method.  Having the GUI close while the process still runs in the background is quite a bug in my opinion.  If I can add a periodic check to see if the queued thread is the last foreground thread, then I can call the method and not have to worry about others that use the class.

Comment: Clean and fast shutdown of an application is non-trivial feature. If you are the only person on a team who think that "no GUI show while process is still shutting down" you should consider getting team into agreement on an expected application's behavior.

Answer (score 4):

You cannot iterate running threads.  Which prevents you from finding out if any have IsBackground = false.  This is rather fundamental, iterating threads can never produce accurate results.  Threads are created and terminated dynamically, you cannot "freeze" your process to ensure that the result accurate.

You need to treat this simply as a bug.  The code of a thread that ignores an explicit request to terminate has a defect.  You'd be wise to make this explicit instead of hoping that the programmer gets it right.  Either by using the BackgroundWorker class and its CancellationPending property.   Or the .NET 4.0 Task class with its CancellationToken structure.  A programmer cannot claim ignorance of these features.  Be careful to get this right in your UI code btw, deadlock is *very* likely.

Comment: I have to agree here. A program that fails to release resources at shutdown is simply buggy.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at `System.Diagnostics.Process.Threads`. That will give you a collection of all the threads in the current process.  Perhaps you can do something with that. Maybe it's as simple as checking to see that yours is the only thread in the process?

Comment: Doesn't work.  You can't map a ProcessThread to a Thread object.